# Permutation with repetitions word problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need help on how to do a task in which it is necessary to make all possible words of 5 letters (it is irrelevant whether these words exist or not).

The letters are:

2 letters "G"

4 letters "Z"

4 letters "V"

2 letters "R"

How many 5-letter words can be written.

I did the case when we have 4 letters Z or V and when we choose 1 more letter.
P (5;4,1) = 5

2•3•5=10
when I multiply the ways, I get the number 30 for this case, but I don't know if this is good or correct, and what to do next, which ways or cases to take

Comment: I suggest **dispensing with any attempt at elegance**, and (very carefully) breaking the problem into cases and subcases.  I would let Case $K$ represent that the combined number of Z's and V's equal $K$, where $K \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$  So, you have $6$ Cases to manually examine.  In each Case, you would have SubCases, depending on how many of the $K$ letters were Z rather than V.

Comment: See also the comment that I left, following the answer of JMoravitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally approach by way of ignoring the limits on the number of times each letter can be used initially, and then subtracting away the cases where we used too many of something.  In this specific problem, note that it is impossible to have used too many of more than one letter simultaneously but in the general problem we might have to deal with that as a possibility and properly use inclusion-exclusion if you were to use this approach.

There are $4^5$ words you can make if we don't care about repeating too many.

Of these, the word ZZZZZ and VVVVV should not be counted since we used too many Z's or V's respectively, bringing our current count down to $4^5-2$

Now, let us count how many are bad because we used too many G's.  This happens if we used three G's and two others, of which there are $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3^2$ instances (*start with choosing where the three G's go and then for each remaining position choose which of the three other letters is used*), or if we used four G's which by similar logic has $\binom{5}{4}\cdot 3$ instances or if we used all five G's.  The related counts for too many R's is identical.

The final total then:

$$4^5 - \left(\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3^2+\binom{5}{4}\cdot 3+1\right)\cdot 2 - 2=810$$

Comment: Different opinions make a horse race.  Your approach is certainly more elegant than the approach in my first comment.  However, I feel that for the new Math student, simplicity is more important than elegance.

Comment: The only thing that matters to me is that I stay within the limits of the given letters but with different combinations and to cover all possible cases and to add it up and get a final number of words of 5 letters.

Comment: @user2661923 and so your suggestion was breaking into... *thirty four* different cases?  I find that morally irresponsible.  There is too much danger of missing a case or repeating a case.

Comment: The problem is that there is an easier way to do it, and that is through the derivative function for permutations, but that way is forbidden to me in this case, therefore the creation is based on the gradual disassembly and addition of all methods at the end

Comment: "*Derivative function for permutations*"?  I don't know what you're talking about @VzasTack.  Perhaps there is a language barrier.  Perhaps you are talking about generating functions and looking at the $x^5$ coefficient in the expansion of $\left(5!\cdot (1+x+x^2/2)^2(1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24)^2\right)$ which is indeed a simple to write approach but requires computer assistance to calculate in a timely manner.  [It does agree with my answer of 810 though.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5%21+*+%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%29%5E2%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%2Bx%5E3%2F6%2Bx%5E4%2F24%29%5E2)

Comment: As for approaching directly versus indirectly... both are perfectly valid in academic settings and depending on the specific problem one may be considerably easier than the other and involves far less arithmetic, such as here.

Comment: @JMoravitz https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLdwE.png I'll add a picture of the formula so you can see if that's the formula I'm talking about, but from what I've looked at what you've posted, I think that's actually it.

Comment: Yes, I do suggest breaking into Cases and SubCases.  This allows the student to learn what he is doing, and to discover shortcuts, based on symmetry, all on their own.  For example, with Case 0, there are $0$ ways, because you can't have a total of $5$ G's and R's combined.  As another example, by symmetry, in Case 4, the number of ways of having 3 Z's and 1 V equals the number of ways of having 1 Z and 3 V's.  This is how the student *learns*.

Comment: @user2661923 and in each of those sub cases,  you break further into additional subsubcases based on number of G's and R's, until you've broken into all the possible cases based on number of G's,R's,Z's and V's... for a total of $34$ such subsubcases, and then for each of those 34 subsubcases you finally count how many outcomes with multinomial coefficients.  Again... it is not incorrect to do but it is amoral to recommend to do here due to the sheer number of cases.  Yes, you can categorize some together with symmetry however even then it is far too many to justify this approach.

Comment: "*This allows the student to learn*"  To learn that it was a foolish approach and a waste of time, perhaps... especially when they then learn there was a much smarter way of going about it just around the corner.  Would you have recommended the same if there were $1000$ letters, $9999$ copies of each available, and we were making words of length $10000$?  Would you really recommend breaking into billions of cases?  Or would you admit my approach is better in that case and say the answer is $1000^{10000}-1000$?

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry ,  I have one question related to the procedure, how did you get ) *2 after the brackets?

Comment: @user2661923 Context is always important and can not be ignored.  Multiple approaches can *and should* be considered, and with experience you can estimate the perceived difficulty of each and pick the one that should be most expedient.  *Ignoring this* and advocating purely only for the "safest" and most "straightforward" approach despite other options being available is *not* how one should approach educating and is not what students should learn.

Comment: @VzasTack the )*2 after the brackets was because what was inside the brackets was for if we had too many G's.  We also have to consider the case of too many R's and the expression would have been identical.  Rather than subtracting the parenthetical phrase twice separately we could simplify the expression by subtracting the parenthetical phrase multiplied by two.

Comment: I understood what you are saying, to avoid unnecessary writing and counting of the same things because R and G have the same number of letters, it is written *2 @JMoravitz Thanks

Comment: In the formula to obtain 810, one argument is missing.  We count all words ($4^5$), we exclude those 2 specific words ZZZZZ and VVVVV then  we exclude words with $3$ or more G, we exclude words with $3$ or more R. By doing this, all words with $3$ or more G and $3$ or more R were excluded twice. But, no problem. There are no words with only $5$ letters, and $3$ or more G and $3$ or more R.

Comment: @Lourrran I addressed that in my post already with the comment at the end of the first paragraph.  "*note that it is impossible to have used too many of more than one letter simultaneously but in the general problem we might have to deal with that as a possibility and properly use inclusion-exclusion if you were to use this approach.*"

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a procedure rather than the final result. I hope you can proceed with these steps:

1. Find number 5 partitions. There are 7 sets according to this website https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integer_Partition/Table: `[[1,1,1,1,1], [2,1,1,1], [2,2,1], [3,1,1], [3,2], [4, 1], [5]]`
2. Find which letters fit on each case: partition `[5]` has 0 word since there is no letter with 5 elements; partition `[4, 1]` has `[{Z, V}, {G, R}]`;
3. It is advisable to consider remaining elements in case not all set elements are used on other partitions as well: partition `[3, 1, 1]` has `[{Z, V}, {Z, V, G, R}, {Z, V, G, R}]`